# C++ simulate the Stack behavior on the heap

Tags: c++, object, memory, stack, heap-memory

First of all, I'm new in c++ world, want to create a stack mechanism,  which the goal the gain of performance, avoiding to call the malloc which rolling a complex gear that cost time(what I think!), the idea is to reserve sufficient space as need(maybe 200MB) and try to manipulate directly this space without the call of malloc, but an error raised like:  `(vcruntime140d.dll) in LearningC++.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCDCDCDCD`, it proves that I have to learn more out of c++(maybe), here is my code:

```
struct Product
{   
    std::string Name;
    float Price;
    float qte;  
}; 
class MyStack
{
    void* p;
    int position;
public:
    MyStack()
    {
        position = 0;
        p = malloc(1024);
    }
    void* Push(rsize_t size)
    {   
        int pos = ((int)p) + position; 
        void* tt  = (int*)pos;
        position += sizeof(size);
        return tt;
    }
};
void main()
{ 
    MyStack* s = new MyStack();;
    int* i1= (int*)s->Push(sizeof(int));
    int* i2 = (int*)s->Push(sizeof(int));
    *i1 = 1234;
    *i2 = 6789;
    Product* p = (Product*)s->Push(sizeof(Product));
    p->Name = "Any product";
    std::cout << *i1 << " - " << *i2 <<"-"<<p->Name << std::endl;
}
```

Here are my questions:

1. Is it possible to do that and push any kind of object(please provide the adequate code)?
2. Will the space that I reserved be sequential in memory(big size)?

Comment: `(int)p` will likely lead to problems if pointers aren't 31 bits on your platform

Comment: `Product* p` needs to be initialised with placement new before you use it

Comment: @Alan Birtles, Ah I found the error:  Name of product(string pointer) is null, just that , i have also to manage that.

Comment: Greate problem with string will raise soon hhh

Comment: @Johnny Mopp, that's greate.

Comment: *it proves that I have to learn more out of c++* No shame in that. Everybody does.

Comment: No need to heap-allocate: just `MyStack s;` should be fine. (You leak your stack.) I recommend using `std::vector` in implementing your stack.

Comment: Also, why is it heterogeneous? When will the destructors be called? Just do `std::vector<int> intStack; int_stack.push_back(1234); intStack.push_back(6789); std::vector<Product> prodStack; prodStack.push_back(Product{“Any product”});`.